# email setup couldn't finish - couldn't open connection to server

Tags: email

Trying to setup my homecall.co.uk email on new Asus T300 Android.
Followed screen instructions got this message:
"email setup couldn't finish - couldn't open connection to server".
Also tried entering exactly same settings as on my PC but with same result
Any ideas, please?
Alan

Comment: If it's doesn't work on your PC (and anywhere else), then I would guess that your connection settings are wrong or their servers are down.

Answer (score 0):

You can open up a command prompt and `C:\ping homecall.co.uk` to ensure that it isn't a server-fault, and if it isn't, then you'll need to poke around after logging into your account to make sure you have the right protocol (i.e. POP, IMAP, etc) as well as the correct server address, the correct ports, and the correct security settings.

Typically, it would be something like

Incoming:
mail.homecall.co.uk  ; port:143
Outgoing:
mail.homecall.co.uk  ; port:587

But those settings are 99% unlikely to work for you.
You simply have to find the settings in your email account.

Typically, you'll find them in your account settings.